# I have a very long 934 entries list and want to display it in a 6 multicolumn menu

Tags: php, css

This is the php code that generates the list and queries the db, I already have some css, but I want to split the list in 6 columns, 16 rows each and add a more ... link at end

```
<?php

$show_manufacturers= true;

// for large lists of manufacturers uncomment this section

/*  if (($_GET['main_page']==FILENAME_DEFAULT and ($_GET['cPath'] == '' or    $_GET['cPath'] == 0)) or  ($request_type == 'SSL')) {
$show_manufacturers= false;
} else {
$show_manufacturers= true;
}
*/
```

// Set to true to display manufacturers images in place of names

```
define('DISPLAY_MANUFACTURERS_IMAGES',false);
if ($show_manufacturers) {

// only check products if requested - this may slow down the processing of the    manufacturers sidebox
if (PRODUCTS_MANUFACTURERS_STATUS == '1') {
$manufacturer_sidebox_query = "select distinct m.manufacturers_id, m.manufacturers_name, m.manufacturers_image
                        from " . TABLE_MANUFACTURERS . " m
                        left join " . TABLE_PRODUCTS . " p on m.manufacturers_id = p.manufacturers_id
                        where m.manufacturers_id = p.manufacturers_id and p.products_status= 1
                        order by manufacturers_name";
} else {
$manufacturer_sidebox_query = "select m.manufacturers_id, m.manufacturers_name, m.manufacturers_image
                        from " . TABLE_MANUFACTURERS . " m
                        order by manufacturers_name";
}

$manufacturer_sidebox = $db->Execute($manufacturer_sidebox_query);

if ($manufacturer_sidebox->RecordCount()>0) {
$number_of_rows = $manufacturer_sidebox->RecordCount()+1;
```

// Display a list

```
$manufacturer_sidebox_array = array();
//      kuroi: commented out to avoid starting list with text scrolling list    entries such as "reset" and "please select"
//    if (!isset($_GET['manufacturers_id']) || $_GET['manufacturers_id'] == '' ) {
//      $manufacturer_sidebox_array[] = array('id' => '', 'text' => PULL_DOWN_ALL);
//    } else {
//      $manufacturer_sidebox_array[] = array('id' => '', 'text' =>  PULL_DOWN_MANUFACTURERS);
//    }

while (!$manufacturer_sidebox->EOF) {
  $manufacturer_sidebox_name = ((strlen($manufacturer_sidebox- >fields['manufacturers_name']) > MAX_DISPLAY_MANUFACTURER_NAME_LEN) ?  substr($manufacturer_sidebox->fields['manufacturers_name'], 0,  MAX_DISPLAY_MANUFACTURER_NAME_LEN) . '..' : $manufacturer_sidebox- >fields['manufacturers_name']);
  $manufacturer_sidebox_image = $manufacturer_sidebox->fields['manufacturers_image'];
  $manufacturer_sidebox_array[] =
    array('id' => $manufacturer_sidebox->fields['manufacturers_id'],
          'text' => DISPLAY_MANUFACTURERS_IMAGES ?
            zen_image(DIR_WS_IMAGES . $manufacturer_sidebox_image,     $manufacturer_sidebox_name) :
            $manufacturer_sidebox_name);
  $manufacturer_sidebox->MoveNext();
}

}
```

} // **$show_manufacturers This is where I need to make changes**

```
for ($i=0;$i<sizeof($manufacturer_sidebox_array);$i++) {
      $content = '';
  $content .= '<li ><a class="hide" href="' . zen_href_link(FILENAME_DEFAULT, 'manufacturers_id=' . $manufacturer_sidebox_array[$i]['id']) . '">';
  $content .= $manufacturer_sidebox_array[$i]['text'];
  $content .= '</a></li>' . "\n";
  echo $content;
}
?>
```

Comment: Why iterate over the data twice?

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a pure CSS solution, you have 2 options:

Use the CSS3 `columns` property, but it only works in modern browsers (some require a prefixed version).  You're guaranteed to get 6 columns no matter what.  Your elements will be presented like a newspaper article (reads top to bottom).

http://caniuse.com/#feat=multicolumn

http://jsfiddle.net/funag/

Use floats.  Float has been around forever, but if you're looking at content that will potentially wordwrap, it might take more effort to line up a specific way.  The up side is that if your device is too narrow to support 6 columns, it will gracefully wrap to however many columns make sense for that width without scrolling.  Your elements will be presented like a paragraph (reads left to right).

http://jsfiddle.net/funag/2/

If you're looking to break up your elements via PHP, what you want is the modulus operator:

```
if ($i % 6 == 0) {
    // insert html tags to force a break
}
```